# Hyperledger Indy. proofs

Tags: hyperledger

When you create a Proof on the Hyperledger Indy Blockchain.

Can you see the DID/Verinym of the person that the Proof was issued to as well as the DID/Verinym of the person that issued the Proof.

Or is the DID of the person the Proof is issued to officiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to have a Verinym  to assign a proof to an DID. And you can't recover the DID of the person the Proof was issued to.